# Data is not saving to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, yii2-basic-app

I'm new to Yii2 framework so I'm having problem with database. I'm working on some project and Having problem with storing my data in database from submit. Code is below. Any ideas?
When I submit my values it does not store in database and it does not show any kind of error it just refreshes my page.

```
Model: Progress.php

    <?php
    namespace app\models;
    use yii\db\activeRecord;
    class Progress extends activeRecord {
        
        private $Emp_id;
        private $date; 
        private $app;
        private $section;
        private $task;
        private $description;
        private $status;
        private $assign_date;
        private $completion_date;
        public function rules(){
            return[
                [['Emp_id','date','app','section','task','description','status','assign_date','completion_date'], 'required']

            ];
        }

    }

Controller:
public function actionCreate(){
        $progress = new Progress();
        $formData= yii::$app->request->post();
        if($progress->load($formData)){
            if($progress->save()){
                yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message', 'Progress report created sucessfully');
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
            else
            {
                yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message','Report creation failed');


        }
    }
        return $this->render('create', ['progress'=>$progress]);
            

    }
view: create.php

<?php
use yii\helpers\html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Progress report';?>
<div class="site-index">
<h1 class="display-4" style="color: #006666; background-color: #CCFF66;"><b>Progress Report </b></h1>
        <h3 style="background-color: #CCFF99; padding: 10px;">Create employee progress report</h3>
    
<div class="row">
 
  
</div>
    <div class="body-content">
       <?php
       $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
            <?php  $items=['1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3',] ?>
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'Emp_id')->dropDownlist($items,['promt'=>'Select Employee id']);?> 
            </div>
          </div>

            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
            <?= $form->field($progress, 'date'); ?>    
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
            <?= $form->field($progress, 'app'); ?>   
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'section');?> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'status');?> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 1500px">
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => '6']);?> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'assign_date');?> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width: 500px">
               <?= $form->field($progress, 'completion_date');?> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

            <br>

            <br>
           <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group" >
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Create records', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>  
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="width: 20px">
            <a href=<?php echo yii::$app->homeUrl;?> class="btn btn-primary">Back home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
    </div>
Table structure: 
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    
      <tr class="table-success">
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Employee ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">App</th>
      <th scope="col">Section</th>
      <th scope="col">Task</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Assign Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Completion Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    if(count($progress)> 0):?>
    <?php foreach($progress as $progress):?>
   <tr class="table-info">
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $progres->id;?></th>
      <td><?php echo $progress->Emp_id;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->date;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->app;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->section;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->task;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->description;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->status;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->assign_date;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $progress->completion_date;?></td>
    
      <td>
    <span style="background-color: #CCCCCC"> <?= html::a('View',['view','id'=> $progress->id],['class' => 'label label-primary'])?></span>
 <span style="background-color: #66ff99"> <?= html::a('Update',['update','id'=> $progress->id],['class' => 'label label-sucess'])?></span>
  <span style="background-color: #ff9980"> <?= html::a('Delete',['delete','id'=> $progress->id],['class' => 'label label-danger'])?></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
   
   
   
  </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                No records found!
            </td>
        </tr>     
    <?php endif; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your table structure

Comment: I shared my table structure in my post

Comment: Does the final html look valid? Are there any javascript errors in browser when submitting? Is the $formData array is populated correctly upon submission?

Comment: Try add `<?= Html::errorSummary($progress) ?>` somewhere in your form - you may have validation errors for fields that are not rendered in form, so errors are also not displayed in this case.

Comment: Also, you should remove all properties from `Progress` model.

Answer (score -1):

you can use GII preview to ensure your model rules

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).